# Help using theorem: A function between metric spaces is continuous if and only if for all open sets in the codomain the pre-image of the set is open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

As in the title, I am trying to work with the following theorem:

$f:M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ is continuous $\iff \forall V \subseteq M_2$ open, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $M_1$.

As a corollary we showed we could replace "open" in the above theorem with "closed". My lecturer gave me two examples and its really confused me. I've tried to draw a few diagrams of the function to distinguish the examples but I'm just not seeing it. Here are the two examples:

Note: My definition for an open set is for any point in the set we can construct an open ball around it that lies in the set. And a set S in $M$ is closed if $M \setminus S$ is open

Example 1: Let   $S=\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : sin(x_1) + x_1x_2 \leq5\}$. Show S is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Proof: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x_1,x_2) = sin(x_1) + x_1x_2$ then let $S=f^{-1}((-\infty,5])$ Then by algebra of continuous functions f is continuous and since $(-\infty,5]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ we get $S=f^{-1}((-\infty,5])$ is closed.

This seems fine to me, we have f is continuous and a closed set in $M_2$ who's preimage is $S$ and this is enough to show S is closed.

Example 2: Let $S=\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \frac{x_2}{sin(x_1^2x_2^3)} > 2 \}$ show S is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Proof: Let  $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_2}{sin(x_1^2x_2^3)}$. This is continuous where defined. Let $S=f^{-1}((2,\infty))$. Since $(2,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and f is continuous $f^{-1}((2,\infty))=S$ is open.

This seems to then imply $f^{-1}((2,\infty))=S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the theorem (the fact its not continuous at $x_1=0$ or $x_2=0$ (or both) seems irrelevant for this example, am I correct?) However this is incorrect because it shows S is open on $(2,\infty)$ not $\mathbb{R^2}$

But the proof for the examples seem to be identical and the only difference between them is the function (both are continuous so I can't see this being a problem) and that one we are proving a set is closed and the other open but since we can interchange closed/open in the theorem this also doesn't seem to be the problem.

I apologize is this is similar to other questions but looking at them and the answers I still can't get my head round the difference between these two examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "because it shows $S$ is open on $(2,\infty)$ not $\mathbb{R}^2$"? You've shown that $S$ is the preimage, under a continuous function $f$, of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and so is open as a subset of the domain of $f$ (which should properly be the maximal subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ on which $f$ is well-defined).

Comment: Are you suggesting the proof works? The solution was given to me by my lecturer who then said it was incorrect because of what you've quoted from my question. That's what I don't get. I will edit in what he believed to be the correct proof tomorrow (unless someone answers before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the set $X=\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \sin(x_1^2 x_2^3) = 0\}$ is much more wild than I initally thought. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin%28x%5E2y%5E3%29%29=0).

This means that the function $f$ is only defined on the subspace $Z=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus X$ and the preimage of $(2,\infty)$ is an open subset of $Z$ with the subspace topology. This does not mean $S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but only that there exists an open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $S=U\cap Z$ (by the definition of the subspace topology).

Comment: Ah yes, I understand what you are saying. So this shows $S$ is open in $Z$ and this does not imply S is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?. However I can't quite grasp the last bit how do we know such an open set $U$ exists such that when you intersect it with $Z$ it is $S$? Thanks.

Comment: It's from the definition of the subspace topology. If you haven't met this topology yet then don't worry - you will soon.

Comment: Okay, thanks Daniel!